# Lubuntu - SD card not showing up!

Tags: lubuntu, sd-card

Using the latest version of Lubuntu (x64). Just popped in the card - doesn't show up anywhere. No idea how I'd go about fixing this, as the other distros I've tried have all had no issues detecting removable media. It's definitely not the SD card or the slot itself malfunctioning, as this card is perfectly usable on other devices.

Comment: Does it detect others? And are you using an adaptor? If not, try using one.

Comment: It does not. USB drives work just fine. I don't own any sort of adaptor, unfortunately. I'd just like the port to work ;)

Comment: Just tried using lsusb... it sees the reader but isn't using it for whatever reason. What the heck.

Comment: Very strange, it sees it on mine. If you go to Application menu, system tools, disks, can you see it? And if so, chose to mount it?

Comment: Nope. Shows my HD, CD, and USB.

Comment: Restarted for the third time, and now it's there. I'm speechless. Problem solved? I'm afraid to remove it now, haha.

Comment: Yeah, very odd... Was it because it was in from the start, and the bios has to detect it?